# Why I get a NoSuchMethodError with scalaz

Tags: scala, sbt, scalaz

Here is an excerpt of my `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.8.3" % "test"
```

It seems that **scalaz 7.1.5.** is evicted by **scalaz 7.2.2**, a dependency of **specs2**.

So I don't understand why I get this compilation error running `sbt test`:

> [error]    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Fatal execution error, caused by scalaz.std.scalaFuture$.futureInstance(Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContext;)Lscalaz/Monad; (FutureOptionScalaz.scala:14)

Comment: Maybe you could use `"specs2-core" % "3.8.3-scalaz-7.1"` ?